# As an American, can I work in New Zealand for a US company?

Tags: new-zealand

I work for a company in the United States, but I work online remotely and can do so from anywhere.

I would like to get an IEP Work Exchange visa. I have looked into it, and it seems that I qualify. Let's assume that I do. My employer is OK with me doing whatever, so long as it won't get them in legal trouble with anyone.

Can I use the Work Exchange visa to work remotely from NZ? Is this legal? I understand that advice here is not formal legal advice, but I want to at least get a sense of what is doable before I invest in pursuing this further.

I've looked into it a bit myself, but pointers to places where I can look to find the answer out on my own are also welcome!

Comment: Have you asked IEP? You'll likely get a response here, but from when I used IEP (and did talks/presentations for them - this is back in 2001) they were very quick to respond and certainly know their stuff.

Comment: I also emailed them about something on this site a few months ago and got a fast response too.

Comment: I sent them an email earlier today. Have not gotten a response yet. As it is the weekend there now I may not get one for a couple of days.

Comment: Incidentally, this may be more suited to expats.stackexchange.  I've flagged it for a mod to decide, but don't crosspost - if they move it, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so my company's legal department said no, trying to do this could get them into legal trouble.

Apparently this has to do with international tax law. Not only will I have to pay taxes in NZ as well as the US (which is fine), my employer would *also* have to become an official NZ employer and pay taxes.

This sounds like a bunch of terrible rubbish to me, but they assure me it is the way that it is. If anyone has any information to the contrary, I would love to hear it. Otherwise, looks like it's a no-go for me.

Comment: That makes sense. Why do you think its rubbish? A NZ company employing an American in the US would have to register in the relevant State, pay FICA and FUTA and provide the employee with W2. Why wouldn't it work the same in the other direction?

Comment: Because I wouldn't be employed in NZ...I'm employed in the US, just living in NZ for a year. I wouldn't be eligible for their equivalent of Social Security, so why would my company have to pay into that? It seems like a win for NZ...a young, skilled professional is willing to come into their country, pay taxes for a year, contribute to the economy, and then leave before getting old and sick and draining the national budget.

Comment: But but but... What do you mean you wouldn't be employed in NZ? If you live in NZ, and work in NZ - you're employed in NZ. Foreign workers in the US are not eligible for social security benefits, yet they still pay the tax - again, why wouldn't it work the same in the other direction?

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure how to explain it any other way. It's totally reasonable for me to have to pay the tax. It's kinda crazy that my employer would have to pay a completely separate set of taxes and fees just for the privilege of having an employee living in the country.

Comment: When you're surprised about some foreign country laws - just think what your country does in the same case. So everything NZ does that surprised you in your story follows the exact same pattern of the US law towards foreigners. If the US does that to kiwis coming to NZ - why wouldn't they do that to Americans coming there? Reciprocity is a very important principle in the international law. In any case, you've discovered the "1099 contractor" solution, but keep in mind that all the FICA/SS taxes (in both countries) will become your own responsibility, they don't just go away.

Comment: For the record, I think that the situation is ridiculous regardless of which country it is. If the US does the same thing, that's crazy too. (Remember, I was always OK with me paying taxes, even if I don't benefit from them. It's the *additional* taxes and hoops my employer would have to jump through that I have a problem with.)

Comment: There's a good reason for that, but that's off topic.