# As an American, what sort of visa do I need to become an independent contractor in New Zealand?

Tags: visa, working-visas, new-zealand

So it seems the best way out of my employment tangle is to become a contractor and do contract work for my US employer ([see previous question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/as-an-american-can-i-work-in-new-zealand-for-a-us-company/) if you are curious of the whole backstory).

I don't think I can become a contractor in NZ with a Work Exchange visa (though I would love to be wrong about this). I am not looking to become a permanent resident, so I don't think the Skilled Migrant visa is for me either.

What should I apply for?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Dronz No, I ended up working for a contracting company who then contracted me back to my employer. It's all very stupid and complicated, honestly, and unnecessarily so. But that's the world we live in. I'm on a Work Exchange visa.

Comment: Thanks for saying. I agree it seems like an awful system. So, you found an existing NZ contracting company. Do you or your client now end up paying double tax?

Comment: @Dronz I'll find out soon; I haven't filed taxes yet this year. But I don't think so -- NZ and the US have some sort of agreement on that regard I believe.

Comment: I hope you update when you find out. I hope the answer is good news!

Answer (score 1):

Immigration New Zealand has a page titled [Requirements for working temporarily in New Zealand](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/worktemporarily/requirements/) which describes all the different categories under which you can apply for a work visa. Some of these are fairly specific (eg. "tour guide" or "Thai chef"), however I don't see a category that might apply to your intent to live in New Zealand and work as an independent contractor for an overseas company.

There is a [Quick check](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/worktemporarily/requirements/quickcheck/) page which summarises the categories (in a way that looks like a flowchart but isn't).